# Ruby concatenate method calls

Tags: ruby, hash

I am developing a ruby application in which I need to concatenate multiple send method calls to access to a complex hash with an array of keys. In order to access to the elements of the hash with send method, I have been using Hashugar gem. For example:

```
hash = { one: 1, two: 2, more: [{ three: 3}, {four: 4}] }.to_hashugar
keys = ['more', 'first', 'three'] # 'first' is the first elements of the array
hash.send( *keys ) # FAIL
```

I have been trying different ways to make it work but I can't do it. Is there any possibility to achieve this?. It doesn't matter if I need to remove Hashugar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you edit to elaborate `# FAIL`. Was an exception raised? If so, what was it? If not, what was returned? That information may help someone figure out the problem when using the gem. I know the question has been answered (rather nicely), but many people may read it in future. It might also earn you some upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) here:

```
keys.inject(hash){|m, key| m.send(key)}
```